# MatFormFieldHarness can't identify from angular unit test

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular-test

This is the test file

```
describe('test', () => { 

 let component: myComponent;
 let fixture: ComponentFixture<myComponent>
 let loader: HarnessLoader;

 beforeEach(() => {
   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(myComponent);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
   fixture.detectChanges();
   loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);
 });

 it('check label', async () => { 
   const form = await loader.getHarness(MatFormFieldHarness); // error line
   const label = await form.hasLabel();
   expect(label).toBeTrue(); 
  }); 
});
```

This is the HTML

```
<div class="units-input-container">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>unit</mat-label>
    <input type="text" required />

  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Failed to find element matching one of the following queries:
        (MatFormFieldHarness with host element matching selector: ".mat-form-field")
        Error: Failed to find element matching one of the following queries:
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the Angular Material's modules used in your component, see below:

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatInputModule,
        NoopAnimationsModule
      ],
      declarations: [AppComponent]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });
```

**NOTE:** I am assuming you are using a reactive form (`ReactiveFormsModule`) and that you may use `mat-input`, that is why I included `MatInputModule`. `NoopAnimationsModule` is required for the test to handle the animations.

For more details check the documentation (see [documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/using-component-harnesses)).

I created a simple example to experiment with the harness framework. See the test **'mat-form-field should detect errors after validations are triggered'** in [github](https://github.com/silver-mx/mat-select-unit-test-example/blob/main/src/app/app.component.spec.ts).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to use form field mdc harness:

```
import {MatFormFieldHarness} from '@angular/material/mdc-form-field/testing';
```

which fixed the issue.